# Set Interface Builder Tag

Tags: xcode

I wanted to know how would I set a tag in the IB of Xcode. I currently have not done anything to try and fix this.

Comment: As a general tip for StackOverflow, you're going to want to try something before asking a question. Then include what you've tried in the question. "I currently have not done anything to try and fix this" usually means its too early to ask a question.

Comment: If you want to set the tag in IB, Swift would not be involved in that setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy. Just go to the storyboard, click on the view you want to tag and look here: [image]

Make sure you're on that 4th tab at the very top, the Attributes Inspector

If you don't see a side bar, make sure the right drawer is opened by tapping on that right-tab-icon on the VERY top right corner (the one that's blue in my pic, it'll be gray if its closed)